# Should a tag be singular or plural?

Tags: discussion, tags

Examples:

- [career] or [careers]
- [design-pattern] or [design-patterns]
- [best-practice] or [best-practices]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tag consolidation and blacklist](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/58/tag-consolidation-and-blacklist)

Comment: @Mark Trapp: It would be highly inefficient to list all tag problems that arise in a single topic... It would become to too busy for one to discuss the problems.

Comment: Prefer `career` over `careers` for consistency with SO and money.SE.

Answer (score 2):

Having thought on this I think it's better to have **plural** tags...

An example with [design-pattern] and [design-patterns].

There might be a question regarding a single design pattern,
but there might also be one regarding multiple design patterns.

Both tags fit well for the first question about a single pattern,
however [design-pattern] doesn't math for the second question about multiple design patterns.

Another reason for plural tags is that a tag lists questions about design patterns, not design pattern.

---

However, there are exceptions to this proposed rule:

- Words that shouldn't be plural,
  it's unlikely that a question will be about [careers] so it should be [career].

Comment: I agree that tags should be plural. One fits into many, but many doesn't fit into one.